# keep filter in URL when using laravel pagination

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5

I want to peform a query with a user specified filter and then Paginate the results.

In my controller I have:

```
public function index(Request $a)
{


    $queryJobCards = JobCardHead::query();

    //Add sorting

    $queryJobCards->orderBy('DateReqLatest','desc');

    //Add Conditions

    if($a->has('CusJobNum')) {
        $CusJobNum = $a -> get('CusJobNum');
        $queryJobCards->where('CusJobNum','=',$CusJobNum);
    }

    if($a->has('Status')) {
        $Status = $a->get('Status');
        $queryJobCards->where('Status','=',$Status);
    }

    // get data and Paginate

    $data = $queryJobCards->Paginate(20);

    return view('JobsByDate.JobsByDate', compact('data'));

}
```

If I go to /JobsByDate?CusJobNum=3224 then I get the filtered results but then when I try to go to the next page I lose the filter and the url becomes /JobsByDate?page=2.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to use `append` method while inserting the pagination link.

```
{{ $users->appends(['CusJobNum' => 3224])->links() }}
```

Update as per your comment:
You will have an aray `['CusJobNum' => 3224 ]` in your `Input` facade whenever the filter is present. While generating the link, what you can do is, insert the `Input::get('CusJobNum')` in your append method's argument. In this way, it will only be appended if the filter is present.

```
{{ $users->appends(Input::get('CusJobNum'))->links() }}
```

Comment: what if no filter is specified ?

Comment: them you would simply use `{{ $users->links() }}`

Comment: I've sorted, I don't know in advance what the filter will be in advance and there could be no filter but I did 'CusJobNum' => $CusJobNum where $CusJobNum is set in the controller and is set to null if no filter. Thanks for your help

Comment: Oh,  I have just read your update ! That will be cleaner thanks

Answer (score 3):

In the filter page, you can have

```
{{ $posts->appends(request()->all())->links() }}
```